# Does a UI Button in Unity have a location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a game where you click a button and it affects another button. I made a grid. If I click a button in this grid I want to have it affect another button's image. However I need some sort identifier which tells me which button is which.

[image]

I'm used prefabs for a button, then made a 5x10 grid prefab of those prefabs. Any guidance towards the right direction would be helpful even if it does not answer the question thank you.

Comment: When instantiating the buttons, why not put them in an array of GameObjects? `GameObject[,] buttonArray`  Then you can access any button from code

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily

First lets make a script
`GridController.cs`

Add a reference to the UI namespace at the top `using UnityEngine.UI;`

Now place all of your grid items in a parent container(can be an empty gameobject)

Now lets start coding

```c#
//Reference parent gameobject
[SerializeField]
private GameObject gridContainer;

//List of all child elements
private List<Button> gridObjects = new List<Button>();

private void Start(){
  //Loop through all children
  for(int i = 0; i < gridContainer.transform.childCount; i++){
    //Add button to list
    gridObjects.Add(gridContainer.transform.getChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<Button>());
  }

  //Set listeners for buttons

  for(int i = 0; i < gridObjects.Count;i++){
    gridObjects[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate{
      DoSomething();
    });
  }
}

private void DoSomething(){
  //Do Something
}
```